# Tricky nginx redirect rules with folders and subfolders

Tags: redirect, nginx, return, http-status-code-301

I want to achieve a 301 redirect like this with nginx:

```
https://www.example.com/foo1/bar1 -> https://www.example.com/foo2/bar2 
https://www.example.com/foo1/bar3 -> https://www.example.com/foo2/bar4 
https://www.example.com/foo1/whatever -> https://www.example.com/foo2/whatever 
https://www.example.com/foo1?argumet -> https://www.example.com/foo2?argument
```

In order to try and acomplish this I am trying to use:

```
#Redirect the longest forced links first
location ~ ^/foo1/bar1 {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/foo2/bar2;
    break;
}
location ~ ^/foo1/bar3 {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/foo2/bar4;
    break;
}
#Redirect everything else except for the matches above according to the rule
location ~ ^/foo1(?:/(.*))?$ {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/foo2/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

It is all good for the first 3 situations. However, for the last situation, I am getting a redirect to:

```
https://www.example.com/foo2/?argument
```

instead of

```
https://www.example.com/foo2?argument
```

...and it breaks the logic of the site.

Can you please help me get this right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
location ~ ^/foo1(/.*)?$ {
    return 301 /foo2$1$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: That breaks situation #3
https://www.example.com/foo1/whatever -> https://www.example.com/foo2/whatever 
It redirect to https://www.example.com/foo2whatever instead of https://www.example.com/foo2/whatever

Comment: It works for me - are you sure you are capturing the `/` within the parentheses?

Comment: For some reason it failed to work when defining the redirect path as absolute and worked when defining the redirect path as relative... 
return 301 /foo2$1$is_args$args; vs return 301 https://www.example.com/foo2$1$is_args$args;